# Preserve Nulls in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4], 'B':[1.0,NaN,3.0,NaN]})
```

I want to convert column B to string preserving the nulls. Please suggest a method on how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can mask:

```
a['B'].astype(str).where(a['B'].notna(), None)
```

Output:

```
0     1.0
1    None
2     3.0
3    None
Name: B, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I am getting a combination of string and float values. I want the entire column to be string values and the float NaN to be None

Comment: @Arcanesaw see updated answer. Just curios, are you trying to pass this to JSON?

Comment: No, I am not. .

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do this:

### ***`np.where`*** method:

```
df['B'] = np.where(df['B'].isna(), np.nan, df['B'].astype(str))
```

### ***`mask`*** method:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].mask(df['B'].notnull(), df['B'].astype(str))
```